# "no such file or directory" when running Docker image

Tags: apache, build, docker

I'm new to Docker and trying to create an image with owncloud 7 on centos 6.
I've created a Dockerfile. I've built an image.
Everything goes right except that when I run the image :

```
docker run -i -t -d -p 80:80 vfoury/owncloud7:v3
```

I get the error :

```
Cannot start container a7efd9be6a225c19089a0f5a5c92f53c4dd1887e8cf26277d3289936e0133c69: 
exec: "/etc/init.d/mysqld start && /etc/init.d/httpd start": 
stat /etc/init.d/mysqld start && /etc/init.d/httpd start: no such file or directory
```

If I run the image with /bin/bash

```
docker run -i -t -p 80:80 vfoury/owncloud7:v3 /bin/bash
```

then I can run the command

```
/etc/init.d/mysqld start && /etc/init.d/httpd start
```

and it works.

Here is my Dockerfile content :

```
# use the centos6 base image
FROM centos:centos6
MAINTAINER Vincent Foury
RUN yum -y update
# Install SSH server
RUN yum install -y openssh-server
RUN mkdir -p /var/run/sshd
# add epel repository
RUN yum install epel-release -y
# install owncloud 7
RUN yum install owncloud -y
# Expose les ports 22 et 80 pour les rendre accessible depuis l'hote
EXPOSE 22 80 
# Modif owncloud conf to allow any client to access
COPY owncloud.conf /etc/httpd/conf.d/owncloud.conf
# start httpd and mysql
CMD ["/etc/init.d/mysqld start && /etc/init.d/httpd start"]
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Vincent F.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After many tests, here is the Dockerfile that works to install ouwncloud (without MySQL):

```
# use the centos6 base image
FROM centos:centos6

RUN yum -y update

# add epel repository
RUN yum install epel-release -y

# install owncloud 7
RUN yum install owncloud -y

EXPOSE 80 

# Modif owncloud conf to allow any client to access
COPY owncloud.conf /etc/httpd/conf.d/owncloud.conf

# start httpd 
CMD ["/usr/sbin/apachectl","-D","FOREGROUND"]
```

then

```
docker build -t <myname>/owncloud
```

then

```
docker run -i -t -p 80:80 -d <myname>/owncloud
```

then you should be able to open

```
http://localhost/owncloud
```

in your browser

Answer (score 1):

I think this is because you're trying to use `&&` within the Dockerfile `CMD` instruction.

If you intend to run multiple services within a Docker container, you may want to check Supervisor. It enables you to run multiple daemons within the container. Check the Docker documentation at https://docs.docker.com/articles/using_supervisord/.

Alternatively you could `ADD` a simple bash script to start the two daemons and then set the `CMD` to use the bash file you added.

Comment: Thank you for this reply. I've tried to start only httpd to check if it would work without the &&. But I get the same issue. I'm on a mac with boot2docker, could it be a part of the problem ?

Comment: Well the script you're starting (in init.d) only starts the Apache process and then exits. You need it running in the foreground.

Comment: If I'm not wrong, based on what I read here : [link](https://docs.docker.com/userguide/dockerizing/), the -d argument to the RUN command starts a container as a deamon. Am I wrong ? So I thought that runing the image with the -d would start and never stop until I send an `docker stop` command.

Answer (score 1):

The issue is that your CMD argument contains shell operations, but you're using the exec-form of CMD instead of the shell-form. The exec-form passes the arguments to one of the exec functions, which will not interpret the shell operations. The shell-form passes the arguments to `sh -c`.

Replace

```
CMD ["/etc/init.d/mysqld start && /etc/init.d/httpd start"]
```

with

```
CMD /etc/init.d/mysqld start && /etc/init.d/httpd start
```

or

```
CMD ["sh", "-c", "/etc/init.d/mysqld start && /etc/init.d/httpd start"]
```

See https://docs.docker.com/reference/builder/#cmd.